# MemoryMappedViewAccessor c++ analog

Tags: c++, .net

I'm looking for **MemoryMappedViewAccessor** С++ analog. It exists?

I want to send data from C++ app to .net app using shared memory. And I need random access. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in C++.  Mostly because none is needed, you can simply access the shared memory with a pointer.  MemoryMappedViewAccessor is required to serialize garbage collected objects to the view.

Which makes shared memory pretty inefficient from managed code.  Do make sure that a pipe or a socket doesn't solve your problem first.  They usually do, dealing with concurrency is also much easier with them.  Shared memory requires a raft of named mutexes to arbitrate access.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Hans! Just now I tested this code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx with MemoryMappedViewAccessor - it works!
But I'm not sure about the performance.
I want to send 1MB of data from c++ app to .net app very often.
I do not know the best way to do it fast.